# Make dropdown width same as textbox width in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to make dropdown width same as textbox width using bootstrap techniques.

[image]

**NOTE: The size should be suto ajusted with respect to the width of the texbox and not relative to page width**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" value="All Sheets" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-auto-close="outside" readonly>
    <div class="dropdown-menu p-0">
      <div class="list-group">
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Sheet1 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Sheet2 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Sheet3 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Sheet4 </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `.w-100` class into the `.dropdown-menu` div.

Sizes documentation can be found on [Bootstrap's webpage](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/sizing/)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" value="All Sheets" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-auto-close="outside" readonly>
    <div class="dropdown-menu p-0 w-100">
      <div class="list-group">
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Sheet1 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Sheet2 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Sheet3 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Sheet4 </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I revised. The size should be suto ajusted with respect to the width of the texbox and not relative to page width

Comment: `.w-100` is 100% width of the parent, not the page. If you want to resize the size of the input, resize its parent using `.col`. I believe its better than adjusting the size of the input itself.